# Checking permissions in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Am new to angular2 and I have a sidebar that i would like to show and hide based on user permissions

This is what i have done

```
 <ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>

  <li [hidden] = "canAccess('dashboard')">
    <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/dashboard">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Then in the dashboard component

```
canAccess(permission:string){
return this._dashboardService.canUser(permission)
  .subscribe( res=>{
    return res
  },
    err=>{
      return false;
    }

  )
```

}

Then the _dashboardservice

```
//http client attaches the access token stored in local storage

  canUser(permission:string):Observable<boolean>{  //returns true or fals
    return this._httpclient.post(this.url,permission) 
     .map(this.extractData)

 }
```

The above goes to an infinite loop always executing the http post

What could i be missing

Comment: above program will go in infinite loop because it keeps checking value is changed or not. this is feature of angular 2 to check change detection. so plz don't use any function inside [hidden] or *ngIf. in place of this you can call a function in ngOnInit() of your component. and store its response in a boolean and that boolean you can use in html part either using *ngIf or [hidden]. if you want i can add answer with some code to explain this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]` in the list items.

Now to the important part of your code getting into endless loop. The *list item's* visibility is bound to `canAccess()` function which returns an `Observable`. It should be bound to a *variable* or *function* or *operation* that returns a `boolean` or a value that can be tested for *truthy/falsy*.

Do something like this:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
    <li [*ngIf] = "showDashboard">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/dashboard">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the code for the component should include the following:

```
private showDashboard: boolean = false;

// Call this function appropriately on component init
canAccess (permission:string) {   

    return this._dashboardService
        .canUser(permission)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.showDashboard = true;
        },
        err => {
            this.showDashboard = false;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I have more than 20 permissions to check it means 20 variables

Comment: In your service call you can get all the permissions as an object (each property representing a permission). Then use it in your HTML template as `*ngIf="permissions.dashboard"`, `*ngIf="permissions.another_section"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Angular detects the changes and every time something is changed it rebuilds the HTML.

This is the line from your template:

```
<li [hidden] = "canAccess('dashboard')">
```

which is, after it is executed and the result is coming back from the server, forcing angular to check whether something was changed; Angular rerenders the component again and of course calls the server again.

Just remember the result in your component variable, fill this variable in `ngOnInit` and use the variable, not the function.

Comment: I have more than 20 permissions to check does it mean that i have to create the 20 variables  to check on init

Comment: create a backend endpoint which returns all of them and store it as an object / array? Or make 20 requests and store them in an object / array?

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI actually your function currently returns an `Observable` and not `boolean` => it is always `true`

Comment: I thought that an observable of type boolean when i subscribe to the observable the result will either be true or false based on what the backend return

Comment: Shed more light

Answer (score 0):

There is an isomorphic authorization library which is called [CASL](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/) . You can read about its integration in Aurelia app:

https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/casl-based-authorization-in-aurelia-app-3e44c0fe1703